# A simple Canvas beyond my mind

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```
    <html>
<head>
<script>
  function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('draw');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      for (i=0,i<=700,i+=10){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(i,700-i);
      ctx.lineTo(700-i,i);
      ctx.stroke();
      }
    } else {
      document.write("Hey idiot, whhich idiot browser you are using? No IE clan here!");
    }
  }
</script> 
</head>
<body onload="draw();"> 
<canvas id="draw" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
</body></html>
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is that this simple code is not working? .............................

Comment: As a lynx user, I feel insulted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your for loop is using commas, it needs semicolons:

`for (i=0;i<=700;i+=10){`

Also this is not OK:

> document.write("Hey idiot, whhich idiot browser you are using? No IE clan here!");

Don't insult your users!

Comment: But insults to one's intelligence are just so much more delicious when they're misspelled.

Comment: Why it is producing just one single diagonal line instead of where it should have been many?

Comment: There are many lines... but at the same position.

Comment: Try replacing       `ctx.lineTo(700-i,i);`
 with       `ctx.lineTo(700-i,2*i);` to see what happens.